# Compare two xml values using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, xml, ajax

OK, so I'm trying to monitor and control something with a Pic-web from microchip. I managed to program it all except for one thing. I need to compare two temperatures that it gives me, and if one of them is smaller that the other then a relay needs to be activated, if its bigger or equal then another relay must be activated. From what I understood Pic-web updates an xml file (status.xml) then the website (using ajax) takes the values from there and displays them on the web page.

The XML file looks like this

```
<response>
<temp0>~temp~</temp0>
<temp2>~tempc~</temp2>
</response
```

The ajax code I use to get the values in my web page

```
document.getElementById('temp0').innerHTML = getXMLValue(xmlData, 'temp0');
document.getElementById('temp2').innerHTML = getXMLValue(xmlData, 'temp2');
```

And to display them I use

```
<span id="temp0"style="font-weight:normal">?</span>
<span id="temp2"style="font-weight:normal">?</span>
```

All I need to do is to compare temp0 with temp2

```
    var temp0 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('temp0').innerHTML)
    var temp2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('temp2').innerHTML)

    if( temp0 < temp2 ) 
    {
        document.getElementById('temp3').innerHTML = '<font color="#00FF00">ON</font>';
    } 
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById('temp3').innerHTML = '<font color="#00FFFF">OFF</font>';

}
```

The I just add `<span id="temp3">?</span>` to display the result

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(getXMLValue(xmlData, 'temp0') < 'temp2')
```

`'temp0'` is not the value of `document.getElementById('temp0')`, it's just a string you made up containing 'temp0'.

You need to assign this to a variable and convert it to a number from a string:

```
var temp0 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('temp0').innerHTML)
var temp2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('temp2').innerHTML)
```

Then use:

```
if(temp0 < temp2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This line looks incorrect...

```
if(getXMLValue(xmlData, 'temp0') < 'temp2')
```

Should it be...?

```
if(getXMLValue(xmlData, 'temp0') < getXMLValue(xmlData, 'temp2'))
```

And unless getXMLValue returns a number of some variety, you will want want to convert it before comparing

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
var temp0 = parseInt(getXMLValue(xmlData, 'temp0'))
  , temp2 = parseInt(getXMLValue(xmlData, 'temp2'));

if( temp0 < temp2 ) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Compare the two temperatures
var temp0 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('temp0').innerHTML)
var temp2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('temp2').innerHTML)

if( temp0 < temp2 ) {
    document.getElementById('temp3').innerHTML = '<font color="#00FF00">ON</font>';
} else {
    document.getElementById('temp3').innerHTML = '<font color="#FF0000">OFF</font>';
}
```

This will display ON if temp2 > temp0

and OFF if temp0 < temp2

thank all of you for your support