# turn on led after a javascript comparison

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, cgi

Ok, so I am monitoring the temperature in the room and controlling some LEDs with a PIC-WEB from microchip. I have to compare two temperatures: the one read by the temp sensor and one that I specify in my webpage). I managed to compare them using

```
if( temp0 < temp2 )
{
document.getElementById('rez').innerHTML = '<font color="#FF0000">Heating</font>';
}
else
{
document.getElementById('rez').innerHTML = '<font color="#00FF00">Cooling</font>';
}
```

wich displays Heating or Cooling in my webpage.

The values of the temperatures are read from status.xml wich looks like this

```
<temp0>~temp~</temp0> // the temp sensor
<temp2>~tempt~</temp2> // the temperature i specify in my webpage
```

What I want to do is to, besides displaying Heating/Cooling to also turn on a LED

The code I use that manages the request is

```
    newAjax.ajaxReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    newAjax.ajaxReq.open("POST", newAjax.url, true);
    newAjax.ajaxReq.send(null);
```

I have buttons in my webpage that I use to control other LEDs

```
<input type="button" value="Turn ON/OFF LED 5" onclick="newAJAXCommand('leds.cgi?led=5');"></input>
```

the leds.cgi file looks like this

```
~led(0)~
```

From what I understand the javascript function newAJAXCommand creates an html GET request for "leds.cgi" with a "POST" value of "led=5"

I can't figure out how to introduce ('leds.cgi?led=5') in the comparison so

```
if (temp0 < temp2)
display Heating and turn on LED5
else
display Cooling and turn of LED5
```

Comment: `<font>` tags? seriously? they are deprecated for *years* now. Besides that, your question cannot be properly answered without you posting the code of the `newAJAXCommand` function (or if that function doesn't exist yet, the return values of your CGI script).

Comment: Props for starting your question with "OK, so" :)

Comment: @ThiefMaster the OP is asking how to write one

Comment: How do you know it's heating or cooling? I suppose that's a return value in leds.cgi, but it's hard to answer this question without some more information

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105170/compare-two-xml-values-using-ajax

Answer (score 0):

Aparrently I just have to add `newAJAXCommand('leds.cgi?led=5')`

like so

```
if( temp0 < temp2 )
{
document.getElementById('rez').innerHTML = '<font color="#FF0000">Heating</font>';
newAJAXCommand('leds.cgi?led=5')
}
else
{
document.getElementById('rez').innerHTML = '<font color="#00FF00">Cooling</font>';
newAJAXCommand('leds.cgi?led=6')
}
```